# scraping iframe content with javascript

Tags: node.js, iframe, node-request

I am trying to scrape a website using node.js. The modules used are request, cheerio and async. Some of the pages have iframes inside which is some text. I am trying to scrape that text. I get the src of the iframe, construct the full url and then make a request using the request module. The html returned keeps saying "This web browser does not support frames".

I tried putting the constructed url in the browser address bar and there I get the text.

I am not sure why this is happening.Please help. How do I scrape the content inside iframe

Sample Code:

```
var $ = cheerio.load(html);
var url = $('iframe').attr('src');
request(url, function(err, res, html){
   console.log(html);
});
```

The printed html shows "This web browser does not support frames" instead of the text it should show when I put the url in the browser.

Comment: Please include your code if possible. It will help us identify the problem.

Comment: I have added some code

Comment: It's hard to answer without specific example. I guess the webpage do some validation in javascript and that's why it works in browser and not in your code.